# Rewrite rules for asp site with multiple string values

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to rewrite tools and hence posting question here.

We are using ASP site with IIS 7 Url rewrite 2.0. We are getting an issue where rules are not working for a specific type of pages.

We have two link one is from the oringal web site what ever it generating and other one which we have mentioned in the pages which will convert it to some data I am posting both link which was generating for the same items.

Pleas suggest what will be the rule to print this on the site address bar.

Actual link : http://example.com/itemMatrix.asp?GroupCode=291&MatrixType=1 
New link by asp code: http://example.com/291_sikaflex-291-10oz_group.htm

So we need to print the new link in the address bar.

We tried this rule and it did not worked.

```
RewriteRule ^/([^_]+)_(.*).htm$ /itemMatrix.asp?ic=$1 [L,I]
RewriteRule ^/([^_]+)_(.*).htm$ /itemMatrix.asp?ic=$1&$3 [L,I]
```

Thanks 
~John